# How to combine these 2 jackson serializations to a single one?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Here's my Pojo:

```
public static class MyPojo {
    private int rootId;
    private String command;
    private Double value;

    // I want this property to be shown at root level
    @JsonIgnore
    public int getRootId() {
        return rootId;
    }

    public void setRootId(int rootId) {
        this.rootId = rootId;
    }

    public String getCommand() {
        return command;
    }

    public void setCommand(String command) {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public Double getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Here's my first serialization method:

```
public static void writeJsonId6() throws JsonProcessingException {
    MyPojo pojo = new MyPojo();
    pojo.setRootId(6);
    pojo.setCommand("property.batch");
    pojo.setValue(129.00);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    String json = mapper.writer().withRootName(Integer.toString(pojo.getRootId())).writeValueAsString(pojo);

    System.out.println(json);
}
```

Json Output: *{"6":{"command":"property.batch","value":129.0}}*

Here's my second serialization method:

```
public static void writeJsonId7() throws JsonProcessingException {
    MyPojo pojo = new MyPojo();
    pojo.setRootId(7);
    pojo.setCommand("property.batch");
    pojo.setValue(88.00);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    String json = mapper.writer().withRootName(Integer.toString(pojo.getRootId())).writeValueAsString(pojo);

    System.out.println(json);
}
```

Json Output: *{"7":{"command":"property.batch","value":88.0}}*

This is what I need:

**{"6":{"command":"property.batch","value":129.0}, "7":{"command":"property.batch","value":88.0}}**

Jackson lib versions: jackson-core:2.0.0, jackson-databind:2.9.0

Comment: `HashMap map = new HashMap();
        map.put(pojo.getRootId(), pojo);
        map.put(pojo2.getRootId(), pojo2);

        String json = new ObjectMapper().writer().writeValueAsString(map);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a `Map<String, MyPojo>`, containing "6" and "7" as keys, and the respective POJOs as values, and serialize that map.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Json Streams:

```
JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
        JsonGenerator generator = factory.createGenerator(new PrintWriter(System.out));
    generator.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
 generator.writeStartObject();
generator.writeObject(firstPojo);
generator.writeObject(secondPojo);
generator.writeEndObject();
```